# Scikits learn define max-iter

Tags: python, svm, scikit-learn

I see in the documentation, there is `max_iter` option in `sklearn.svm.SVC` class constructor
http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC

But whenever I try to use it, I'll get an error message like this

```
svc = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel_option[kernel_gene], degree=degree_value, gamma=gamma_value, max_iter = 1000)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_iter'
```

Here is my code:

```
svc = svm.SVC(kernel=kernel_option[kernel_gene], degree=degree_value, gamma=gamma_value, max_iter = 1000)
```

Since kernel_option, degree and gamma value is alright. What's wrong here? Do I have some kind of syntax error or what?

**EDIT:**
@Ogrissel has found the problem. I use 0.12.1, while the documentation is for 1.3
Since 1.2.1 is the most recent stable, is there any solution (define max_iter) for `sklearn.svm.SVC`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the development version of the documentation that matches the current state of the master branch on the git repository. You are likely running a released version of scikit-learn. Please use the [documentation matching your version of scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/support.html#documentation-resources) or [build scikit-learn from the source repo](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/index.html#git-repo) instead.

Comment: Is there any solution for 1.2.1?
Thanks :)

Comment: @goFrendiAsgard: if you mean 0.12, then no, there isn't. The underlying LibSVM code had to be modified to enable the `max_iter` option.

Comment: Sorry, and yes, I mean 0.12
Ok, porting to 0.13 seems to be the only solution

Comment: Note that at this time 0.13 is not released yet. You will have to use the ongoing development branch from github.

Comment: Is max_iter the number of max epochs?